# Windows Installer gets terminated by Data Execution Prevention

Tags: windows-xp, windows-installer, dep

I'm trying to install something, and all of a sudden Windows' DEP kills Windows Installer. This has happened to me before. Is there a fix for this I'm not aware of? I'm on XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to try is to see if DEP is causing the problem, so you need to turn it off.

> 1. Click Start
> 2. Select Control Panel
> 3. Select System
> 4. Click the Advanced tab
> 5. In the Performance region select Settings
> 6. Click the Data Execute tab in the dialog box that opens
> 7. Select Turn on DEP for all programs and services except for those I select
> 8. Click Add.
> 9. The open dialog box will open. Browse and select your application.
> 10. Click Open
> 11. Click Apply
> 12. Click Ok
> 13. Reboot

Comment: Isn't that unsafe?

Comment: I mean, disabling protection looks like a bad thing to do.

Comment: You can re-enable after just to test to see if it works

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've got the [latest version](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5a58b56f-60b6-4412-95b9-54d056d6f9f4) of Windows Installer first.

However, you may find that the package you're attempting to install is incompatible with DEP - some custom actions or third party extensions are. In which case you'll need to follow Systech's suggestion, or get an updated version of the package.